# Suddenly Lost Visual Studio Typescript Intellisense

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using visual studio community 2015 writing typescript in a MVC 6 application.
Everything was working fine last time, when I opened the solution today typescript lost its intellisense, When I compile using gulp it compiles, but visual studio doesn't want to see anything. when I add the "reference directive" on the top of the files the intellisense work, but visual studio still cannot understand html in react tsx files and highlight the tags with red lines which if you hover on them you see "React is not found"! I wonder what happened suddenly!! I didn't change anything I was just writing ts and tsx files.

Answer (score 0):

This happened with me most of the time. I do these steps when VSCode intellisense doesn't work in my mac:-

1) Command+shift P for opening commandPallete.

2) Search for Reload Window.

Comment: There is nothing called Reload Window, and Ctrl Shift P opens the target device. you said it happened with you most of the time, could you please explain the solution better.

Comment: I am using mac, keys i used to open command pallete is Command+shift P...You can find it in View-> commandPallette.See if that helps...

Answer (score 0):

Try Reset all settings it will start working:-

Tools -> Import and Export Settings -> Reset all settings

Comment: after resetting the settings the new files are working, but the old files no